# Populating a list view from another list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I need to achieve this: I have a sqlite table with this data

```
slno Type   Level_1 Level_2      Level_3
1 Animals   Cat     Null         /sdcard/Video
2 Animals   Cat     Null         /sdcard/PDF
3 Birds    Aves     HummingBird  /sdcard/video
```

I should have a list view with Animals and Birds , clicking on Animals shows me Cat, while Bird shows me Aves. Then so on until the content - which has to be played depending on the type. Now this can be achieved by creating a lot of Activities say for Animals level - pass level_1 for Activity_2 and so on and get the list views. But in my case the levels may not be fixed - there might be a level_4 coming in where there is content - so the activity creation has to be dynamic and cannot be static  - how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented by modifying the base adapter to include multiple levels.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create lots of activity.If understand your problem completely then i will suggest you go for Expandable List View like in image [image]

This link has best tutorial for this design  [Go through it](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/05/expandable-lists.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response - Yes I ve looked at the expandable list set and if I understand it correctly it only allows a fixed number of hierarchical levels - but in my case I ll have to dynamically adjust as per the data . Is there any way this can be achieved ? Also is there a way to make the list data look like the "Pulse" App data view (in the above screenshot)?

Comment: If you changing hierarchy dynamically then draw this expandable listview again.Now it will show new elements with new data

Answer (score 0):

Just Use only One activity, and Set this Activity's Data Source on calling activity, like

intent.putExtra("KEY", DataSource);

in onCreate() method get this DataSource from intent, like

intent.getParcelableList("KEY");

and start this activity only with new data source, or play the file according to the level.